# Can you explain why I need a new form for update function in Symfony?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I have an action that creates a form.  The form's action then points to the following function:

```
  public function executeUpdateInlineForm(sfWebRequest $request)
{

  $overdueInvestigation = Doctrine_Core::getTable('investigation')->find( $request->getParameter('id'));    
  $this->form = new investigationInlineForm($overdueInvestigation);

  $this->processInlineForm($request, $this->form);
}
```

What I don't understand is why I need instantiate a new form when all I am trying to do is save the existing one?

I am asking this because my form has fields from two different tables and I want to be able to update both tables when the user submits.  I therefore need to work out the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with a class so you must instantiate it. When the form is submitted, your script that originally rendered the response and everything that went into it is long gone. This function doesn't know about it anymore.

Comment: Am I getting the table investigation in order to store any fields in the form to avoid overwriting these fields should the form's fields be empty?  So, if my table row didn't have any data in it already, I wouldn't have to get the database record and store it in the form?

Comment: Nicola: Either way is possible, depending on what you're looking to do. Normally after a form submission you would fill the form class using the $request data so it can be validated and saved, but it really depends on what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

The reason symfony ordinarily creates a new form upon form submission is to handle displaying the form with any invalid fields highlighted to let the user re-try.